# Where do I find extensive taxonomy repositories?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Where might one find an extensive repository of taxonomy terms divided into different vocabularies?

Cheers,

Comment: Did you look into this location  ,,  Admin -> Structure -> Taxonomy

Comment: You mean on your site? Or you are looking for something like resource page with zips containing "the list of all cities in all countries" and similar data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Open Calais (http://www.opencalais.com/) They have an extensive tagging system that is free to use. They even have a Drupal module you can use: [OpenCalais](http://ttps://www.drupal.org/project/opencalais). Details from its project page:

> The Calais Collection is an integration of the Thomson Reuters' Calais web service into the Drupal platform. The Calais Web Service automatically creates rich semantic metadata for the content you submit – in well under a second. Using natural language processing, machine learning and other methods, Calais analyzes your document and finds the entities within it. But, Calais goes well beyond classic entity identification and returns the facts and events hidden within your text as well. The web service is free for commercial and non-commercial use. It requires registration to obtain an API Key.

You can use such a service to find/suggest tags for your corpus of content.

Answer (score 0):

The Autotag module - as the name suggests - automatically tag blog posts etc. for you. You can choose what content should be autotagged. It relies on a third party service to tag content.

Opencalais provides a free service with up to a large number of transactions per day (50.000 immediately, can be extended). There are also other options but this seems to be the one that will work best in my case (multi-user blogs in a closed community).

I have found a module to import .CSV files: https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv
However I have not found any repositories except for a list of public services where the tags themselves were numbers only the description showed what it meant.

So currently it seems the only two options are 1. creating vocabularies yourself or 2. rely on a third party service to do the work for you.